# '^M' character at end of lines

Tags: sql, unix, newline, carriage-return, line-endings

When I run a particular SQL script in Unix environments, I see a '^M' character at the end of each line of the SQL script as it is echoed to the command line.
I don't know on which OS the SQL script was initially created.

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It's caused by the DOS/Windows line-ending characters. Like Andy Whitfield said, the Unix command dos2unix will help fix the problem. If you want more information, you can read the man pages for that command.

Comment: On some systems (i.e. Ubuntu) the name of this command is "fromdos"

Comment: You can get the tool on OSX very easy with `brew install dos2unix` when you have homebrew installed

Answer (score 81):

Fix line endings in `vi` by running the following:

`:set fileformat=unix`

`:w`

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. Many thanks. (saved installing dos2unix, a tool I'd probably only use once)

Comment: this doesnt remove the `^M`s for some reason. reference file: `/etc/timidity/fluidr3_gm.cfg`.

Answer (score 41):

The cause is the difference between how a Windows-based based OS and a Unix based OS store the end-of-line markers.

Windows based operating systems, thanks to their DOS heritage, store an end-of-line as a pair of characters - `0x0D0A` (carriage return + line feed). Unix-based operating systems just use `0x0A` (a [line feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_feed)). The `^M` you're seeing is a visual representation of `0x0D` (a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return#Computers)).

[dos2unix](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) will help with this. You probably also need to adjust the source of the scripts to be 'Unix-friendly'.

Comment: I wouldn't say current versions of Windows have any kind of DOS *heritage*. They still have compatibility restraints, though.

Comment: This is the easy way, is you do an automatic conversion tool. Thank's

Comment: But why `^M`? Why the '^'? Why the 'M'?

Comment: Because it's a "control character". 

"^" is the visual representation of clicking the control key. Underneath its just specific bytes, the ^ is how the editor represents them.

Comment: Upvoted for the clear and informative answer. By the way, I just tried all different CSV options in Excel "Save as..." but all of them produce `\r` which I can see by the `^M` on Linux with `cat -e filename.csv`. Also tried Calc from Apache OpenOffice which is now on the Microsoft Store, and same result. Conclusion, I'll use Excel or Calc for editing convenience and just get rid of `^M` with `dos2unix` before `git commit`.

Answer (score 25):

The easiest way is to use `vi`. <strike>I know that sounds terrible but</strike> its simple and already installed on most UNIX environments. The ^M is a new line from Windows/DOS environment.

from the command prompt: `$ vi filename`

Then press "`:`" to get to command mode.

Search and Replace all Globally is `:%s/^M//g` "**Press and hold control then press V then
M**" which will replace ^M with nothing.

Then to write and quit enter "`:wq`" Done!

Comment: How to replace it in emacs?

Comment: Thanks for the expanation on how to type the ^M character! I would replace it with \r instead. So I did :%s/^M/\r/g

Comment: This doesn't work for `nvim` inside the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Comment: @herbertD, maybe this will help for Emacs
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DosToUnix.
dos2unix also comes by default with Doom Emacs

Answer (score 14):

Try using dos2unix to strip off the ^M.

Answer (score 10):

In vi, do a `:%s/^M//g`

To get the `^M` hold the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, press <kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> (Both while holding the control key) and the `^M` will appear. This will find all occurrences and replace them with nothing.

Comment: To replace the ^M with a unix friendly line break: `:%s/^M/\r/g`

Answer (score 8):

The SQL script was originally created on a Windows OS.  The '^M' characters are a result of Windows and Unix having different ideas about what to use for an end-of-line character.  You can use perl at the command line to fix this.

```
perl -pie 's/\r//g' filename.txt
```

Comment: Sure, you CAN use perl, but would you suggest perl over dos2unix?

Comment: I'm just providing an alternative, since four people already said to use dos2unix.

Comment: Yes, I found this useful because I am on a backward workstation working in an office with a prehistoric IT department.

Except I used a variation: perl -pi -e "s/\x0D/\n/g" file.csv

Answer (score 7):

The ^M is typically caused by the Windows operator newlines, and translated onto Unix looks like a ^M. The command dos2unix should remove them nicely

dos2unix [options] [-c convmode] [-o file ...] [-n infile outfile ...]

Answer (score 5):

```
C:\tmp\text>dos2unix hello.txt helloUNIX.txt
```

Sed is even more widely available and can do this kind of thing also if dos2unix is not installed

```
C:\tmp\text>sed s/\r// hello.txt > helloUNIX.txt
```

You could also try tr:

```
cat hello.txt | tr -d \r > helloUNIX2.txt
```

Here are the results:

```
C:\tmp\text>dumphex hello.txt  
00000000h: 48 61 68 61 0D 0A 68 61 68 61 0D 0A 68 61 68 61 Haha..haha..haha  
00000010h: 0D 0A 0D 0A 68 61 68 61 0D 0A                   ....haha..  

C:\tmp\text>dumphex helloUNIX.txt  
00000000h: 48 61 68 61 0A 68 61 68 61 0A 68 61 68 61 0A 0A Haha.haha.haha..  
00000010h: 68 61 68 61 0A                                  haha.  

C:\tmp\text>dumphex helloUNIX2.txt  
00000000h: 48 61 68 61 0A 68 61 68 61 0A 68 61 68 61 0A 0A Haha.haha.haha..  
00000010h: 68 61 68 61 0A                                  haha.
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to `dos2unix` command would be using standard utilities like `sed`.

For example,
dos to unix:

```
sed 's/\r$//' dos.txt > unix.txt
```

unix to dos:

```
sed 's/$/\r/' unix.txt > dos.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

To replace ^M characters in vi editor use below

open the text file say t1.txt

```
vi t1.txt
```

Enter command mode by pressing `shift + :`

then press keys as mentioned `%s/^M/\r/g`

```
in above ^M is not (shift + 6)M instead it is (ctrl + V)(ctrl + M)
```

Comment: Your last line is what I was missing from all the previous answers. I kept getting 'no matches found bc I was doing shift+6, so I did what every hacker would and circumvented my misunderstanding with my own solution:
record a macro to do $ to go to end of each line and then press x, just repeat macro for num of lines in file.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove ^M from the files directly via sed command, e.g.:

```
sed -i'.bak' s/\r//g *.*
```

If you're happy with the changes, remove the .bak files:

```
rm -v *.bak
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert DOS/Windows (\r\n) line endings to Unix (\n) line endings, with tr:

```
tr '\r\n' '\n' < dosFile.txt > unixFile.txt
```

[Post about replacing newlines from the Unix command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252010)

Answer (score 0):

`od -a $file` is useful to explore those types of question on Linux (similar to dumphex in the above).

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, if you don't want to set the $/ variable and use chomp() you can also do:

```
$var =~ /\r\n//g;
```

My two cents

Answer (score 0):

As [already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64798/5362795), Windows programs like to terminate lines with *CRLF*, i.e. `\r\n` instead of the Unix/Linux standard `\n`. Since I don't need all the features of `dos2unix` I replaced it by adding the following to my `~/.bashrc` which removes the `\r`:

```bash
function win2unix() {
    tmp=$(mktemp) && tr -d '\r' < $1 > $tmp && mv $tmp $1
}
```

Now when I want to get rid of those `^M` characters created e.g. when I export a CSV file from Excel or Calc, I can just do something like:

```
win2unix filename.csv
```

You could also use `sed` or something else, of course. By the way, I use `cat -e $filename` to visualize the `^M` endings.

Answer (score -1):

Another vi command that'll do: `:%s/.$//`  This removes the last character of each line in the file.  The drawback to this search and replace command is that it doesn't care what the last character is, so be careful not to call it twice.

Comment: Why mention it if you know it's not reliable?