# Replace Windows newlines in a lot of files using sed - but it doesn't

Tags: linux, sed

I have a lot of files that end in the classical `^M`, an artifact from my Windows times. As this is all source code, git actually thinks those files changed, so I want to remove those nasty lines once and for all.

Here is what I created:

```
sed -i 's/^M//g' file
```

But that does not work. Of course I did not type a literal `^M` but rather `^V^M` (ctrl V, ctrl M). In vim it works (`:%s/s/^M//g`) and if I modify it like this:

```
sed -i 's/^M/a/g' file
```

It also works, i.e. it ends every line with an 'a'. It also works to do this:

```
sed -i 's/random_string//g' file
```

Where `random_string` exists in the `file`. So I can replace `^M` by any character and I can remove lines but I cannot remove `^M`. Why?

Note: It is important that it is just removed, no replacing by another invisible char or something. I would also like to avoid double execution and adding an arbitrary string and removing it afterwards. I want to *understand* why this fails (but it does not report an error).

Comment: Is the character at the end of the line? If so this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749/m-character-at-end-of-lines

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use `sed` for this? It seems easier to just run `dos2unix`. (That said -- your `sed -i 's/^M//g' file`, using `^V^M` to insert the `^M`, works fine for me.)

Comment: Oh, I did not know about this tool. It may be easier, I will check it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That character is matched with `\r` by `sed`. Use:

```
sed -e "s/\r//g" input-file
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I had to do

```
sed -e "s/\r/\n/g" filename.csv
```

After that `wc -l filename` Showed correct output instead of 0 lines.