# reading unformatted data, intel ifort vs Ibm xlf

Tags: formatting, fortran

I'm trying to shift from intel ifort to IBM xlf, but when reading "unformatted output data"(unformatted I mean they are not the same length), there is problem. Here is an example:

```
program main
implicit none
real(8) a,b
open(unit=10,file='1.txt')
read (10,*) a
read (10,*) b
write(*,'(E20.14E2)'),a,b
close(10)
end program
```

1.txt:

```
0.10640229631236
8.5122792850319D-02
```

using ifort I get output:

```
0.10640229631236E+00
0.85122792850319E-01
```

using xlf I get output:

```
' in the input file.  The program will recover by assuming a zero in its place.e invalid digit '
0.10640229631236E+00
0.85122792850319E-01
```

Since the data in the 1.txt is unformatted, I can't use a fixed format to read the data. Dose anyone know how to solve this warning?

Comment: Is there an apostrophe in the input file?  Or any character besides digits, decimal point and "D"?    Your reads are "list directed".

Comment: Thanks @M.S.B. for the commons. Yes it seems to have some character after 0.10640229631236 that costs this warning. When I write those numbers to a new file by hand(change line after 0.10640229631236 by the enter key), this warning goes away. I "cat -v" these two files: With the warning file I get 
0.10640229631236^M
8.5122792850319D-02
while the no warning files I get
0.10640229631236
8.5122792850319D-02 Do you know what that M stands for and where it comes from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749/m-character-at-end-of-lines

Comment: @george - perhaps you should add an actual answer with this, so this won't stand as an unanswered question and gather unnecessary attention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Question answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@M.S.B wrote:

> Is there an apostrophe in the input file? Or any character besides digits, decimal point and "D"? Your reads are "list directed".

The OP Wrote:

> Yes it seems to have some character after 0.10640229631236 that costs this warning. When I write those numbers to a new file by hand(change line after 0.10640229631236 by the enter key), this warning goes away. I `cat -v` these two files: With the warning file I get 0.10640229631236^M 8.5122792850319D-02 while the no warning files I get 0.10640229631236 8.5122792850319D-02 Do you know what that M stands for and where it comes from?

@agentp gave the link:

> ['^M' character at end of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749/m-character-at-end-of-lines)

Which explains that ^M is the windows character for carriage return