# Remove hidden characters in a text file

Tags: excel, text

I was working in a tab delimited text file that I want to edit on excel. I've got the warning message that if I saved this file after editing I might lose some of the file's proprieties. So I pressed on continue but then it saved it with hidden characters that doesn't appear unless I use the "less" command. It also appears at the end of each line as "^M".

I just want to get rid of it so I could use this file in R. Is there any easy way to get rid of that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749/m-character-at-end-of-lines