# Doesn't PhpMyAdmin generate correct JSON export files? With what to replace ^M character on Unix?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, phpmyadmin

I exported an SQL table in a JSON file using PhpMyAdmin tools.

I got a file like this:

```
/**
 Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin
 @version 0.1
 */

// Database 'table_name'
// ...

[{"id": 7,"field1": "value1","field2": 2,"field3": "Lorem^M
ipsum^M
dolor^M
sit^M
amet","field4": "value4"}]
```

It's clear that the first lines (that are comments are not valid because JSON doesn't allow comments).

I know that [`^M`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64749/1420197) is *caused by the DOS/Windows line-ending characters*.

Running `jsonlint myexportedfile.json` after removing the comments I get this:

```
[Error: Parse error on line 1:
dolorld2": 2,"field3": "Lorem
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined']
```

Still, is this a valid JSON format? What character am I supposed to replace `^M` character? New line (`\\n`), or?

I want to be able to do `require("./myexportedfile")` in NodeJS and to get the data and then to make some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after removing the lines with comments you can apply the following perl command on the file:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g'
```

its changing the file inplace (!) removing all the  `^M` in them and making a real unix file out of it.

Comment: I run `perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g'  myexportedfile.json` but it just replaced `^M` characters with nothing. The json file is still invalid... :-(

Comment: Its not about phpMyAdmin. The `^M` is the value of your JSON data and replacing this with "nothing" is the only thing you can do at this time. I assume this data is coming from some textbox where the user has hit on RETURN or copied DOS text into it. Removing the ^M and pasting into JSONLINT gave me an ok?

Comment: I found the following workaround: export as csv, replace `^M` with nothing, convert to JSON.